# PHP 8.0+ how to append strings to unknown SESSION variables in a clean concise way without Warnings

Tags: php, append

Previously code would look like this in PHP 7.4 :

```
$_SESSION['message'] .= "Sorry; That file or location can not be found.";
```

Which would append to an existing string or set as contents for a new string. And my error logs (with notices turned off) would be beautifully empty.

With PHP 8.0+ now, [undefined array elements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) (amongst other things) are classed as **warnings** rather than Notices.

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "message" in /index.php on line 29

I understand the conceptual logic behind this *Warning* but in the instance of the above code it presents the need for a verbose workaround; something like:

```
if(array_key_exists('message', $_SESSION)){
    $_SESSION['message'] .= "Sorry; That file or location can not be found.";
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry; That file or location can not be found.";
}
```

Or possibly;

```
$_SESSION['message'] = (array_key_exists('message', $_SESSION)?$_SESSION['message']:"") 
                       ."Sorry; That file or location can not be found.";
```

Which for thousands of SESSION elements across dozens of websites is really cruddy looking; harder to read and generally a big bloat to avoid Warning messages that seem to serve no purpose.

I don't want to turn warning messages off.

Are there any possible workarounds; such as any way in the php.ini to avoid this trigger for concatenation actions (`.=`) ? Can we somehow escape superglobals or more specifically `SESSION` data (and `POST` data perhaps) which it's impossible to know it's value before concatenation.

Comment: `@` is bad practise for surpressing error reporting. However actually in this case with string concatenation it is a *possible* route, but I'd prefer a non-@ route if one can be found as `@` this will suppress *all* errors (although to be totally honest string messages like this won't often have many other errors) . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise workaround can be:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = ($_SESSION['message'] ?? ''). " string here";
```

Which is probably as good as it gets.